# Хранить состояния флага в localStorage?

Tags: vue.js

Как хранить состояния флага в localStorage ?
Затем его передавать в какой-то блок через v-if ?

```
handleInstallButtonClick() {
    this.isAlert = false;
    localStorage.setItem('is-alert', this.isAlert);
    this.isAlert = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('is-alert'));
    console.log(this.isAlert);
  },
```

Comment: Можно создать `watch` на поле `isAlert` и внутри этой функции заполнять другое поле из local storage при необходимости.

Comment: как реализовать

Comment: Очень просто. В конпоненте есть поле isAlert. По умолчанию сделай его null. Затем в хуке создания компонента created, по-моему, заполняешь поле из local storage, а если в local storage значение отсутствует, то false

Comment: Затем, в разделе watch нужна функция которая при изменении этого поля сохраняет значение поля в local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте компьютед с сеттером.

```
computed: {
  isAlert: {
    get() {
      return localStorage.getItem("is-alert")?.toLowerCase() === "true";
    },

    set(value) {
      localStorage.setItem("is-alert", value);
    },
  },
}
```

в шаблоне это будет использоваться, как обычная переменная

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="isAlert" />
```